# How do I launch a URL from my application on Android?

Tags: android, url, browser

How can I code my Android application to start the web browser to display a given URL?

(I'd rather not embed a web browser component into my app, but rather want to start the Android web browser to show the URL.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use an Intent with the correct action and data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 4):

In case if you have the website displayed on your view and you want it to make it clikable and direct user to particular website You can use:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

In same way you can use different attributes of autoLink(email, phone, map, all) to accomplish your task...