# How do I redirect a button to a URL or website(browser) Android?

Tags: android, url, redirect, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I launch a URL from my application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060949/how-do-i-launch-a-url-from-my-application-on-android)

I can't seem to figure out how to work on this. I need to click a button that will redirect to a URL / Website. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GoogleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button english = (Button)findViewById(R.id.google);//button name in xml file
        english.setOnClickListener(google); // on button click listener 
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener google
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
         startActivity(intent);


            }

        };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
             Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much but whenever I click unto the button, it doesn't show up the site. (google.com). just stays on the same page. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
load_url.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
 startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

**Update:**

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testtone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        });
    }


}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement what you have given. And, it's not redirecting to the URL. :( Do I need to do something else with these? or in the manifest?

Comment: @XiangCorneliaSorceress: Did you gave this permission in you manifest if no means kindly add it <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: I already did. But the directing site / URL (google.com) doesn't show up in my emulator. :(

Comment: @XiangCorneliaSorceress: It works fine for me... If you get any error messages in Logcat

Comment: no error messages in logcat. It just doesn't show up. :( Idk what to do. Im just a plain newbie in here. :/

Comment: @XiangCorneliaSorceress: i update my code, refer it

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally worked! :)